# How to get PHP to remove a proxy from .txt once it's used

Tags: php, curl

Okay so what i basically want is once a proxy from "proxies.txt" has been used for it to then be moved to a file such as "used.txt" so only fresh un-used proxies remain in the "proxies.txt" because the id grabbing program i have starts from the very top of the list every time it's started and an ID can only be grabbed once per 24 hours from each proxy.

```
{
switch(@$argv[1]) {
    case '0':
    default:
        $list = fopen('proxies.txt', 'r');
        while(!feof($list))
        {
            $proxy = fgets($list);
            $idGen->generate($proxy);
        }
        fclose($list);
    break;
}
$loop++;
usleep(50000);
$idGen->report('Starting loop #'.$loop);
```

}

Also is there a way i could get it to delete dead proxies current curl set-up is

```
$tries = 0;
    $xData = '';
    $timeout = 3;
    //echo "Tries -> ";
    while($xData=='' && $tries < 3) {
        $ch = curl_init(); //curl init :D
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_URL,                'website.com/idauth.php?t='.rand(100000000000,1000000000000000000000000000000000)); //url
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_PROXY,              $proxy);
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,     1);
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,     $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,            $timeout);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $rdata = $data;
        if(@$data{0} == '<') { 
            return;//Bad Proxy Detected.
        }
        if(strpos($data, 'Not Found') != FALSE) { 
            $data = '&UserId=0&k1=0&k2=0';
        }
        if($data != '&UserId=0&k1=0&k2=0') {
            if(strpos($data, '&k2=0') != FALSE) { 
                $data = '&UserId=0&k1=0&k2=0';
            } else {
                $xData = $data;
            }
        } else {
            echo $data."\n";
        }
        $tries++;
        }

    if($xData=='') {
        return;//Dead Proxy
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the entire proxy list into an array, do manipulations and re-write out the entire file once its complete.

May work better in a database when you are doing multi-threading in your requests which seems natural to your problem. In that case just delete, etc.

somewhere outside the scope of your top function:

```
$proxies = array()
function load_proxies() {
        global $proxies;
        $list = fopen('proxies.txt', 'r');
        while(!feof($list))
        {
            $proxy = fgets($list);
            $proxies[] = $proxy;
        }
        fclose($list);
}

function get_proxy() {
    global $proxies;
    return array_pop($proxies);
    //here you may want to save over proxies.txt, and write out the chosen proxy to used.txt
}
```

Comment: To be honest it's my friends script and i have limited knowledge i really don't have much of a clue on how to do what you just mentioned lol.